# Grafana+Influxdb and unix timestamp

Tags: timestamp, grafana, influxdb

I have a problem with the dashboard - something is being rendered that is not in database at all. As far as I can see, the problem will be somewhere in the processing of timestamps.

[image]

But when I look at the data tab - it shows me wrong. There are also timestamps from the future. And according to these, a graph is drawn for me, which in that case is wrong.
[image]

For example:

```
time: 1680790676000
```

( it is - GMT: Thursday 6. April 2023 14:17:56)

in data tab is two hours more:

```
2023-04-06 16:17:56
```

And then graph not corresponding.
Can you any idea how resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Grafana auto-corrects provided timestamps to timezone specified for user (can be seen in time range drop down), assuming that time provided by data source is in UTC.

If your data contains timestamps in time zone other than UTC, I believe you should use something like `timeShift()` to convert to UTC.

[Similar question](https://community.grafana.com/t/time-zone-influx-spread-wrong-time-frame/72664) on Grafana's forum

Comment: I just tried this already. When I try timeshift or tz('UTC) neither method works for me.

Comment: What "neither works for me" means? You want to say that once you change timezone output doesn't change? @cesc

Comment: When my tz preferences in Grafana to `Coordinated Universal Time`,then the values match. Against the current time of(UTC+2), for example, the Browser, the graph (x-axis) is shifted back by 2 hours. So Example - I currently have 9:00 in the browser but 7:00 on the x-axis, with this value setting it fits backwards. But the x-axis shows the offset. The values are and the graph is fine in UTC, but our current time is UTC +2:00. And I can't get it to match. When I align the x-axis, the graph doesn't match again. (According to Query Inspector, it already has some values from the future)